# converting bash (e.g. ssh) to c++ using std::system

Tags: c++, bash, ssh

I am trying to convert my bash code to c++ code. I have something like this:

```
ssh ${USER}@${HOSTS[0]} "bash -c \"cd ${PROGRAM_PATH}; svn update; rm -rf build; make\""
```

How can I convert this to C++ using std::system? I tried this:

```
const std::string bashFunc("bash -c \"cd " + k_programPath + "; svn update; rm -rf build; make\"");
const std::string func(getSSH(k_user, server) + " \"" + bashFunc + "\"");
std::system(func.c_str());
```

When I print func, it looks alright. But when I run it, it doesn't connect with ssh and only tries to do the bash commands on my local folder.

EDIT: This is what the string looks like:

> > ssh username@server "bash -c "cd ./path/to/folder; svn update; rm -rf build; make""

Comment: Probably a bad idea. `svn` has a library, and there is OpenSSL etc..

Comment: What's wrong with using bash in the first place? And could you print the actual string you formulated?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: It's just a small side project for myself, nothing too complicated.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I want to add multi threading because one ssh command after another just takes too long. I edited my question.

Comment: And changing the original line to say `make -j N` where `N` is some suitable number isn't working?

Comment: You don't need to use threading for this -- you can use background processes in native bash and get parallelism with much less complexity.

Comment: Also, passing a string into a `system()` call is **extremely** error-prone compared to performing an `execve()` call with an explicit array of arguments.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: That's not what I want to do. I call ssh to a lot of servers to check if a specific program is still running, but checking >100 servers per ssh serially just takes too much time.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I wanted to try parallelism with bash at first, but it looked kinda hard to do, so I went with C++ threads, because at least I know those :)

Comment: If you asked a question about the specific aspect of parallelism in bash that was giving you trouble, perhaps we could help with that. Seriously -- I *promise* that it'll be easier and less error-prone than invoking a bunch of shells from C++.

Comment: (Also, using string concatenation to substitute variables into your shells gets you into a place where you need to worry about shell injection vulnerabilities; your code would be much more secure if you passed string literals through the environment rather than substituting them into code).

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Alright, I might just ask. It can't hurt to know both ways. Don't worry about security, it's just a quick and dirty private project, nothing for official release ;)

Comment: @Charles Duffy: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117247/checking-per-ssh-if-a-specific-program-is-still-running-in-parallel) is my bash question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to escaping the quotation marks, I also had to escape the slashes, like this

```
const std::string bashFunc("bash -c \\\"cd " + k_programPath + "; svn update; rm -rf build; make\\\"");
```

That works now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `system()` in any but the most trivial cases -- it adds an extra layer of shell parsing, each of which increases the amount of quoting and escaping involved in your code. Instead, use a member of the `execv()` family of calls:

```
char * const command[] = {"bash", "-c", "yourcommand", NULL};
execv("/usr/bin/bash", command);
```

Be sure to `fork()` before reaching this code so that you don't implicitly exit your script, and `wait()` in the parent process if you want it to read the exit status of its child.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this. Instead of fork() I'll use std::async though.

Comment: It's actually mandatory that you use `fork()`. Trying to make it inline using `std::async()` will result in your process terminating the first time you use an exec*-series call.