# checking per ssh if a specific program is still running, in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have several machines where I have a program running. Every 30 seconds or so I want to check if those programs are still running. I use the following command to do that.

```
ssh ${USER}@${HOSTS[i]} "bash -c 'if [[ -z \"\$(pgrep -u ${USER} program)\" ]]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi'"
```

Now running this on >100 machines takes a long time and I want to speed that up by checking in parallel. I am aware of '&' and 'parallel', but I am unsure how to retreive the return value (task completed or not).

Comment: Have you looked into using [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/) for doing this? It runs over ssh and doesn't take too much to get going.

Comment: @vikramls: It's just for a simple private project, so this seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Oh -- you're using this for process supervision? Ewww. The Right Thing would be to use a real process supervision framework -- your Linux distro almost certainly comes with one.

Comment: Aside: If these are shell-local variables, not environment variables (and you can't export bash arrays into the environment, so `HOSTS` **must** be a shell-local variable!), best practice is to use lower-case variable names to avoid conflicts. Upper-case are reserved for environment variables and builtins.

Comment: Oh -- I missed the part about wanting to track which hosts complete successfully and which don't. The easiest way to support that relies on having bash 4 or newer; is that available for you?

Comment: I edited my script to provide the aforementioned functionality. Note that it now needs bash 4.0 as a minimum version.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Yes, I have bash 4.3, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lets all connections complete before starting any in the next batch, and thus can potentially wait for more than 30 seconds -- but should give you a good idea of how to do what you're looking for:

```
hosts=( host1 host2 host3 )
user=someuser
script="script you want to run on each remote host"

last_time=$(( SECONDS - 30 ))
while (( ( SECONDS - last_time ) >= 30 )) || \
      sleep $(( 30 - (SECONDS - last_time) )); do
  last_time=$SECONDS
  declare -A pids=( )
  for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    ssh "${user}@${host}" "$script" & pids[$!]="$host"
  done
  for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid" || {
      echo "Failure monitoring host ${pids[$pid]} at time $SECONDS" >&2
    }
  done
done
```

---

Now, bigger picture: Don't do that.

Almost every operating system has a process supervision framework. Ubuntu has Upstart; Fedora and CentOS 7 have systemd; MacOS X has launchd; runit, daemontools, and others can be installed anywhere (and are very, very easy to use -- look at the run scripts at http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html for examples).

Using these tools are the Right Way to monitor a process and ensure that it restarts whenever it exits: Unlike this (very high-overhead) solution they have almost no overhead at all, since they rely on the operating system notifying a process's parent when that process exits, rather than doing the work of polling for a process (and that only after all the overhead of connecting via SSH, negotiating a pair of session keys, starting a shell to run your script, etc, etc, etc).

Yes, this may be a small private project. Still, you're making extra complexity (and thus, extra bugs) for yourself -- and if you learn to use the tools to do this right, you'll know how to do things right when you have something that *isn't* a small private project.

Comment: Do I have to install the framework on the machines I want to monitor? If yes, I can't do that. I have no root access.

Comment: @gartenriese, that's why I pointed out frameworks that already ship with their various operating systems. Several of these (not all of them, granted) have access and support for letting unprivileged users set up their own monitored processes.

Comment: Alright, I might look into these if I can't come up with something quick. Can I do something like this too: checkPart ${i} & pids+=( $! ). I mean calling a function in parallel. I tried it but it doesn't seem to wait. It advances almost instantly.

Comment: Calling a function in a backgrounded subshell (which is what `myfunc &` does) is *supposed* to return instantly. You need to use `wait` to check on whether it succeeded or not. (Note that because such functions are run in out-of-process shells, they can't change variables inside the parent shell).

Comment: By the way, `checkPart ${i}` is *exactly* the same as `checkPart $i`. If you want to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion of your variable's contents on expansion, you need `checkPart "$i"` -- quotes have that effect; curly-brackets don't.

Comment: So I can get a 0 or 1 return value for example?

Comment: The return value is given by `wait` when you pass it the PID of the subprocess you want to check for.

Comment: If you look at the script as currently edited, by the way, you'll see that it checks the return status and names hosts that fail.

Comment: Does failing mean in the case of a custom function returning 0, or -1?

Comment: `0` is success. If you want your function to indicate failure, it should `return 1`.